# How to customize forge formatter in vscode

Tags: solidity, foundry, forge, formatting, vscode

I'm using [Foundry toolchain](https://book.getfoundry.sh/) and [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for my smart contracts development.
As  [suggested by the Foundry documentation](https://book.getfoundry.sh/config/vscode) I applied the vscode integration tweaks and I'm using forge formatter to format my code,
here is the relevant part from my vscode settings file:

```
"[solidity]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "JuanBlanco.solidity"
},
"solidity.formatter": "forge",
```

It works well, but now I would like to customize the formatter (there are [many options for configuration](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/config/formatter)). How can I apply the forge formatting configuration to my vscode?

Comment: You can't customize the formatter in VSCode. You need to do it in a Foundry config file. See how I do it in my [Foundry template](https://github.com/PaulRBerg/foundry-template/blob/df980088181d556a01a2edf01546cd9e112b2447/foundry.toml#L34-L42).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked by adding the configuration block to my `foundry.toml` file.

```
[fmt] # See https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/config/formatter
int_types = "short"
line_length = 120
bracket_spacing = true
multiline_func_header = "all"
number_underscore = "thousands"
quote_style = "single"
ignore = ['./script/**/*']
```